# Website HTTP requests blocked on public wifi

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, httprequest, restangular

I am in the midst of trying to get a website deployed on an Amazon EC2 instance. The application works as expected when using my work WiFi, my home internet, or even on my phone’s 3G connection. It doesn’t work properly when I attempt to connect use a 'public wifi', such as one you might get at a coffeeshop or other public places: GET requests to the back-end do not occur/are blocked. Front-End is intact, but the requests are blocked. In Chrome's developer tool under Network, it shows 'Provisional Headers are Shown'.

If I do a curl at the appropriate port number, it stalls until timeout. When I curl on a good internet connection, it gives me HTML immediately.

**Basic breakdown of my application:**

MEAN stack, using RestAngular to send HTTP requests, Express and CORS are used to accept and respond to any requests. Front-End uses Webpack during deployment.

I have two suspects: CORS or AWS

```
CORS settings:
       'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':  true
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':config["cors"]["allowedUrl"] ## my domain name
       'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'
       'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, X-Requested-With, X-AUTHENTICATION, X-IP, Content-Type, Accept, authorization'
```

**AWS Security group Inbound settings:**

HTTP(TCP): Port 80, Anywhere
All TCP, Anywhere
SSH, Port 22

I’ve tried having it set to ‘All traffic’, but the problem persists.

EDIT:

I looked at net-internals, and saw that it seems to get hung up on the TCP connect attempt. It outputs an os_error of 60, although I'm not sure what that means. Best I could find online is that it means its not a data stream.

```
654408: SOCKET
pm/my-website.com:3001
Start Time: 2018-05-30 09:16:35.655

t= 6075 [st=    0] +SOCKET_ALIVE  [dt=75271]
                    --> source_dependency = 654407 (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_JOB)
t= 6075 [st=    0]   +TCP_CONNECT  [dt=75271]
                      --> address_list = ["35.153.17.199:3001"]
t= 6075 [st=    0]     +TCP_CONNECT_ATTEMPT  [dt=75271]
                        --> address = "35.153.17.199:3001"
t=81346 [st=75271]     -TCP_CONNECT_ATTEMPT
                        --> os_error = 60
t=81346 [st=75271]   -TCP_CONNECT
                      --> net_error = -118 (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)
t=81346 [st=75271] -SOCKET_ALIVE
```

Comment: Are you sure the public wifi connection you are using isn't the issue? Maybe they block AWS IP blocks?

Comment: If I read it correctly your front-end is getting touched but the back-end isn't when accessing your service over free WiFi. If so then try digging through the front-end's logs (perhaps even run in an attached terminal with verbose). Also are you able to SSH normally when on free WiFi? If so then the access points maybe doing something to non-encrypted data that your front-end is barfing on instead of forwarding.

Comment: @S0AndS0 -- I made an edit above showing the output from chromes net internals. It gives an os_error that I'm not familiar with. Is there a way to manage sockets on an ec2 instance on amazon?

Comment: FWIW, definitely not a CORS error.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with AWS lightsail. Frontend react app is working fine but backend calls *only* on public wifi (like a public library) are failing with a connection error. Any help?

Comment: @valem I never specifically solved this, it was a project I was working on in my spare time. If I recall correctly, the problem seemed to originate in Nginx, and I think it was due to not having a reverse-proxy properly implemented (I'm sorry if that comes off buzz-wordy, not a front-end developer by trade). Hope this helps!